# Error: "Cannot start Object Push Profile (OBEX OPP) service" when tried to transfer file from Android phone via bluetooth,Why?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, android

In Windows 8.1 when I try to send file from Andoid device to PC via bluetooth it shows - Error: "Cannot start Object Push Profile (OBEX OPP) service" 
As far as I gusess,in Windows bluetooth stack there is no support for OBEX FTP and OBEX OPP profile.
Now is there any update for Windows or third party stack which will support OBEX FTP and OBEX OPP and also compatible with Windows 8.1 64bit?